# Pattern to use Google Firestore as an aggregate of an internal API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application that has a single collection (itinerary data) that will have many (40,000+) entries.  This data needs to be queryable and included in the firestore.

When I attempted to import the data set, I realized that executing so many writes would be costly and use up most of my allowance, so bulk importing this data isn't an option, unless there is a way to do so without executing so many writes.

My mentor floated the idea of serving the itinerary data as a separate API, and using firestore pulling it into firestore on demand.  This would spread the burden of writes over time.

I'm curious about my options here, and would like some advice on how to execute.

What would my client side request look like?  Would it involve using a cloud function?  How do I ensure the data in the firestore is up to date if my API data changes?

Comment: It sounds like you have two completely different problems here.  One is getting data into the system, and the other is caching data on the client from that same system.  Adding a client cache isn't going to help you with importing the data.  So I'm kind of confused what you're really trying to solve here.

Comment: Firestore has offline caching built in, so that's taken care of.  This question is more about getting data into the system.

Comment: OK, could you edit your question to focus on the specifics of that problem, and remove the part about caching? I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have updated.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: I still see that you're still describing two separate problems - importing data, and querying/caching data.  On Stack Overflow, posts need to be limited to a single question or issue at a time.  If your problem with caching is resolved, edit the question to focus only on importing the data, and provide the details of that one **specific** issue.

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm no longer asking about caching and don't even use that word in my question.  I feel like everything I'm asking is directly related to the pattern I'm asking about, which would start with a query in firestore, or maybe a cloud function if that's suggested.

The first two paragraphs simply provide context of what I've tried already, and how I've landed at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "what would the query look like"?  When dealing with Firestore, when we say "[query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)", we mean fetching data.  If you are adding data to Firestore, that's not a query - you're writing code for that to add each document where it belongs.  For adding data, there is really no alternative than [adding](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) each document individually, and paying for the write for each document.  There are no shortcuts for that.

Comment: The question asks about a pattern to pull from an API and store it in Firebase triggered from the client somehow.  I have updated my question to not use the word 'query'.  The goal here is to spread the burden of import over time, ensuring only data that is in demand exists in the firestore. That's not a shortcut, it's an approach.  If that approach is impossible/bad/not recommended, I'd love that to be the answer and figure out something else.

Comment: I think you're just going to have to make up something that works for your requirements. There's nothing special going on here. Firestore itself does not have any capabilities you can make use of.  Just start coding and experiment with it.